# Freopen() not working in SDL

Tags: console, sdl, cout, freopen

I tried using freopen() to redirect the "cout" function to the console, but it doesn't produce the desired effect. Instead of just double clicking on the executable and having the console show it's message, I need to use a command prompt or a batch file, and that's a problem, because I want the user to be able to close the console after the message has been displayed without closing the SDL window. This is supposed to be a console application. I apologize if I am not clear enough.

Answer (score 0):

If using freopen() doesn't work the [SDL Console FAQ](http://sdl.beuc.net/sdl.wiki/FAQ_Console/) gives a tutorial on recompiling the SDLmain library that is relatively easy to understand, especially if you already have MSYS and MinGW installed. You can use the resulting SDLmain library instead of your current one and it should work (It did for my project).